# DataGrid сброс выделения при изменении ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Программа представляет собой мини диспетчер задач. Каждую секунду происходит обновление списка процессов в ProcessViewModel, что, в свою очередь вызывает обновление DataGrid, который привязан к этой коллекции. При обновлении сбрасываются такие свойства DataGrid как выбранная строка, сортировка столбцов и т.д. Есть ли легкий способ этого избежать или придется вручную через код сохранять и применять эти свойства?

ProcessViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Task_Menager.ViewModel
{
    internal sealed class ProcessViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<Process> _processes;
        private Process _selectedProcess;

        public ProcessViewModel()
        {
            Update();
            var updateTimer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1)
            };
            updateTimer.Tick += UpdateTimerOnTick;
            updateTimer.Start();
        }

        public Process SelectedProcess
        {
            get { return _selectedProcess; }
            set
            {
                _selectedProcess = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public List<Process> Processes
        {
            get { return _processes; }
            set
            {
                _processes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void UpdateTimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Update();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            Processes = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Task_Menager.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Task_Menager.ViewModel"
        Title="Диспетчер задач" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <viewModel:ProcessViewModel x:Key="ProcessViewModel" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProcessViewModel}}" IsReadOnly="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProcess, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Processes, Source={StaticResource ProcessViewModel}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding ProcessName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID процесса" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:
Используйте вместо

```
private List<Process> _processes;
```

поле

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Process> _processes;
```

В конструкторе

```
public ProcessViewModel()
{
    _processes = new ObservableCollection<Process>();//создали коллекцию
    Update();
    var updateTimer = new DispatcherTimer
    {
        Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1)
    };
    updateTimer.Tick += UpdateTimerOnTick;
    updateTimer.Start();
}
```

Так, вы не обновляете источник (он остается тем же списком, который сам рассказывает, какие изменения в нем произошли).
Чтобы заработало корректно, правим еще один момент:

```
private void Update()
{
    //запоминаем выбранный id
    var id = SelectedProcess.Id;
    //очищаем
    Processes.Clear();
    //заполняем
    foreach(var p in Process.GetProcesses().ToList())
    {
        Processes.Add(p);
    }
    //Устанавливаем выбранный элемент
    SelectedProcess = Processes.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Id=id);
}
```

Итак, сортировки и фильтры не изменились, текущий элемент установлен. Все должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь осталась только проблема с тем, что DataGrid теряет фокус при обновлении. Можно присваивать ему фокус при SelectionChanged, но тогда будет сложно выяснить имел ли он фокус до этого события или нет.